# Limiting response size with httplib2

Tags: python, http

Is it possible to limit the response size with httplib2?    For instance if it sees an HTTP body over X bytes the connection will just close without consuming more bandwidth.   Or perhaps only download the first X bytes of a file.

Comment: Request Library can do this job easily                         import requests beginning = requests.get('http://example.com/').iter_content(1024).next()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the server is sending the response body size in the `Content-Length` response header field, you can do it yourself.

First, call `Http.request(method="HEAD")` to retrieve only the headers and not the body. Then inspect the `Content-Length` field of the response to see if it is below your threshold. If it is, make a second request with the proper `GET` or `POST` method to retrieve the body; otherwise produce an error.

If the server isn't giving you the Content-Length (or is lying about it), it doesn't look like there is a way to cut off the download after some number of bytes.