# Protection against downloading too big files

Tags: python, http

I have a website where people can fill in a url of a newsfeed. My server will then download that newsfeed and parse it. How can I protect myself against too big newsfeeds?

With too big I mean: so big that downloading takes too much time, bandwith or filespace. Can I set a limit on the amount of MB to receive? Or limit the time downloading maybe?

Comment: There's not enough information here. How are you downloading? Do you get a content-length (if applicable) - can you retrieve the size, if not, do you think it's liable to "lie" to you.... can you truncate the stream after reading 'n' amount etc... etc...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362721/limiting-response-size-with-httplib2 -> HEAD HTTP method

Comment: @Jon Clements How I am downloading? That's what I am asking advise for. urllib? httpconnection?

Comment: @Alberto Megía That answer tells that it is not possible to cut off after a certain amount of bytes. But what about cutting of after a certain amount of time? Using a seperate process for downloading and killing it if it takes too long?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every http client lib I know (at least in Python) gives you or can give you a *stream*:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://example.com/big-file', stream=True)
>>> r.raw
<requests.packages.urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x101194810>
```

Now you have response headers available, maybe Content-Length is present:

```
>>> r.headers.get("content-length")
'33236'
```

It's up to you how you read from the stream:

```
>>> r.raw.read(10)
'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03'
```

If I wanted to limit the download by max time and max size, I would do something like this:

```
t0 = time.time()
total_size = 0
while True:
    if time.time() - t0 > time_limit:
        raise Exception("Too much time taken")
    if total_size > size_limit:
        raise Exception("Too large")
    data = r.raw.read(8192)
    if data == "":
        break  # end of file
    total_size += len(data)
    output_file.write(data)
```

The web server doesn't stop working when you quit HTTP connection prematurely :)

Comment: So I have to install the requests library? I am using Python 3.3

Comment: No, you don't have to. I am just used to requests, because I like its simple API. You can use urllib, it's in Python standard library: http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html#examples

Comment: You set me on the right track. I now use feed=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read(1000000) . This will not download the whole file, but only what is needed.